# How to make a bacjground image not to move

Tags: android, image, screen

I want to ask how can I make an image/background image not to move when the phone's keyboard is available? Or at least to be cover by the keyboard or something?

In my situation when I call fro the keyboard the image is moved automatically above the keyboard and it doesn't even stay in back ground.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that value of **adjustPan** for [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) would do the trick for you.

You may also try the other values and see what's best for your case.